# Location of public class method 'new' of 'Class'

Tags: ruby

Ruby's `Class` class lists two methods named 'new':

- [`Class::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Class.html#method-c-new) is a public class method
- [`Class#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Class.html#method-i-new) is a public instance method

But when I do:

```
Class.methods(false)
#=> []
```

which is supposed to list singleton methods (which I am assuming what class methods are), I get an empty array. Why is this so? Where is `Class::new` defined?

Answer (score 3):

The methods shown as `::new` in the documentation are usually `#initialize`, for example [`Range::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Range.html#method-c-new):

> #### new(begin, end, exclude_end=false) → rng
>
> Constructs a range using the given `begin` and `end`. If the `exclude_end` parameter is omitted or is `false`, the `rng` will include the end object; otherwise, it will be excluded.

This is because you create instances via:

```
r = Range.new(0, 2)       #=> 0..2
```

Rather than:

```
r = Range.allocate        #=> nil..nil
r.send(:initialize, 0, 2) #=> nil
r                         #=> 0..2
```

That's exactly what `::new` does – it creates a new instance via `allocate`, sends it `initialize` (passing arguments) and returns the instance.

The actual `new` method is inherited from `Class` (since `Range` is an instance of `Class`) – [`Class#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Class.html#method-i-new):

> #### new(args, ...) → obj
>
> Calls `allocate` to create a new object of *class*’s class, then invokes that object’s `initialize` method, passing it *args*. This is the method that ends up getting called whenever an object is constructed using .new.

Just like `allocate`, `inherited` and `superclass` (and the instance methods from `Class`' ancestors like `Module` as well):

```
Range.method(:new)
#=> #<Method: Class#new>

Range.method(:allocate)
#=> #<Method: Class#allocate>

Range.method(:ancestors)
#=> #<Method: Class(Module)#ancestors>
```

So if you call `Class.new`:

```
my_string_class = Class.new(String)
#=> #<Class:0x007fdf5485b200>
```

you just invoke `Class#new` which is (again) equivalent to:

```
my_string_class = Class.allocate
my_string_class.send(:initialize, String)
my_string_class
#=> #<Class:0x007fdf5484beb8>
```

One notable exception is `Struct` which in fact provide its own `new` class method:

```
Struct.method(:new)
#=> #<Method: Struct.new>
```

Unlike other classes, `Struct::new` does not return instances of `Struct` but instances of `Class` (which are subclasses of `Struct`).

Comment: No I think you are wrong. Calling Class.new is not the same as Class#new. When Class.new is called rb_class_initialize gets executed , 
where as when you call new on some other class rb_class_new_instance gets called. What I want to know is in which class' method table is the former stored.

Comment: @OmarKhan _"When Class.new is called rb_class_initialize gets executed"_ – because of `Class#new`, it calls `allocate` and then sends `initialize`. In the C code, `Class#initialize` maps to `rb_class_initialize`.

Comment: My understanding is that `Class#new` is an instance method that calls `rb_obj_alloc(klass)` and then calls ` rb_obj_call_init` to initialize the object(see code on the [documentation page](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html#method-i-new)), it **does not** call `rb_class_initialize`. However when we call `Class.new` `rb_class_initiallize` does get called. 'Class.new' creates two objects, a class object and a metaclass object, A.new (where A is not the Class class) creates a single object only.

Comment: OK I get what you are saying, did not read the code for `rb_class_initialize` properly. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr summary**:

> Why is this so?

Because it's not a singleton method.

> Where is `Class::new` defined?

It isn't. The *call* `Class.new` is just calling `Class#new` (since `Class` is an instance of itself). The *documentation* for `Foo::new` is actually the documentation for `Foo#initialize` for *any* class `Foo`, including `Class` itself.

---

If you want to know something about Ruby, it is often a good idea to ask her herself:

```
new_method = Class.method(:new)
#=> #<Method: Class#new (defined in Class at core/alpha.rb:90)>
```

The [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) method returns a [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html) object representing the method. (Methods aren't objects in Ruby themselves, but you can get a reflective proxy object that represents a method.)

You can ask a `Method` where it is defined using the [`Method#owner`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-owner) method:

```
new_method.owner
#=> Class
```

As you can see, [`new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new) is defined in [`Class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html) and not in `Class`'s singleton class.

You can also ask a `Method` about the location of its Ruby source code using the [`Method#source_location`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-source_location) method:

```
new_method.source_location
#=> ['core/alpha.rb', 90]
```

What this tells us is that `Class#new` is defined in the file [`core/alpha.rb` on line 90](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/alpha.rb#L90-L104):

```
def new(*args)
  obj = allocate()

  Rubinius.asm(args, obj) do |args, obj|
    run obj
    run args
    push_block
    send_with_splat :initialize, 0, true
    # no pop here, as .asm blocks imply a pop as they're not
    # allowed to leak a stack value
  end

  obj
end
```

The method is partially implemented in bytecode for performance reasons, but it is basically just:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate

    obj.__send__(:initialize, *args, &block) # because initialize is private
    #obj.initialize(*args, &block)

    obj
  end
end
```

Now, you might ask yourself: why is there an entry for [`Class::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-c-new) in the RDoc documentation, if that method doesn't exist? Well, [RDoc](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc) knows about the relationship between `#initialize` which is the method you define but usually don't call directly and `Class#new` which is the method you call but usually don't define, and it will document `#initialize` as `::new` if it exists.

So, what we really want to look at, is `Class#initialize`:

```
initialize_method = Class.method(:initialize)
#=> #<Method: Class#initialize (defined in Class at core/class.rb:15)>

initialize_method.owner
#=> Class

initialize_method.source_location
#=> ['core/class.rb', 15]
```

[This is the source](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/class.rb#L15-L32):

```
def initialize(sclass=Object, name=nil, under=nil)
  raise TypeError, "already initialized class" if @instance_type
  raise TypeError, "can't make subclass of Class" if Class.equal?(sclass)

  set_superclass sclass

  # Things (rails) depend on the fact that a normal class is in the constant
  # table and have a name BEFORE inherited is run.
  under.const_set name, self if under

  if sclass
    Rubinius.privately do
      sclass.inherited self
    end
  end
  super()
end
private :initialize
```

`Class#initialize` essentially does three things:

- set the superclass
- optionally assign the class to a constant to give it a name
- call the [`Class#inherited`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-inherited) hook method of the superclass

If you want to know what the relationships between some of the core classes that magically spring into existence at the beginning are, you can take a look at the initialization code of some Ruby execution engines, e.g.

- [Rubinius](https://rubinius.com/): [`VM::bootstrap_class` in `machine/ontology.cpp`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/machine/ontology.cpp#L85-L186)
- [JRuby](https://jruby.org/): [`org.jruby.Ruby.initRoot` in `core/src/main/java/org/jruby/Ruby.java`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/Ruby.java#L1297-L1364)
- [IronRuby](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironruby): the initial classes are generated by a program, the generator is in the directory [`Src/ClassInitGenerator`](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironruby/tree/master/Src/ClassInitGenerator)
- [MRuby](http://mruby.org/): [`mrb_init_class` in `src/class.c`](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/master/src/class.c#L2271-L2366)

---

Note: depending on what Ruby implementation you use, obviously the places where those methods are defined and how exactly they are defined may vary.

Comment: Suppose that `A` is a user defined class, are you suggesting that when I do `Class.new` and `A.new` the same method, `Class#new`, gets called? If so why is that when we do `Class.new` a metaclass is made while `A.new` does not create a metaclass? Does it check the class of the receiver to alter its behavior?

Comment: `Class#new` delegates to the `initialize` method of the newly created object. `Class#initialize` is different from `A#initialize`, ergo, they can behave differently. (`Class#new` is essentially: `obj = allocate; obj.initialize; return obj`.)

Comment: Also, if by "metaclass" you mean "singleton class", then what you say is not really true. Every object has a singleton class in Ruby. Period. (Okay, there may be some exceptions around immediate value types.) Now, some implementations only actually create the singleton class lazily, when someone looks at it, but that is a private internal implementation detail, an internal optimization that must not be observable from user code.

Comment: OK now I get what you mean. I got confused because I thought that declaring a class using the keyword `class` was that same as calling `Class.new` with a block and since creating a class using the keyword does not call `Class#new` I thought `Class.new` must be different. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`new` is defined as a instance method of `Class` class, rather than a singleton method:

```
Class.instance_method :new     # => #<UnboundMethod: Class#new>
```

Tricky to note: `Class` (object) itself is also an instance of `Class` (class).

```
Class.instance_of? Class       # => true
```

Comment: "Class (object) itself is also an instance of Class (class)" - I stared at the C code for a few minutes, trying to find which line exactly makes it so, but gave up. Do you have it, perhaps? :)

Comment: Sergio: I think in Ruby MRI, it is made by `Init_class_hierarchy()` in `class.c`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: In Rubinius, it is in [`VM::bootstrap_class` in `machine/ontology.cpp`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/machine/ontology.cpp#L85-L186). I find the more declarative style of Rubinius more readable, but YMMV. In JRuby, it is [`org.jruby.Ruby.initRoot` in `core/src/main/java/org/jruby/Ruby.java`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/Ruby.java#L1297-L1364).

Comment: You are confusing the two methods when you do 'Class.new' it is not the same as doing 'A.new' where A is some class.

Comment: @OmarKhan: Yes, it is, because `Class` is just some class, too.

Comment: I believe not: consider `Object.method(:new).unbind == Class.instance_method(:new)`.